# Programar una tarea en Windows Server desde vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows-server-2012, schedule

Buenas,

Estoy programando una tarea desde vb.net con estos parámetros. Genera correctamente la tarea y se ejecuta. Esto funciona correctamente en local, pero necesitaría que esa tarea se crease en el servidor. ¿Alguna idea?

```
Using tService As New TaskService()
    Dim Fecha As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(txtFDesde.Text + " " + txtHDesde.Text)
    Dim tTime As New TimeTrigger()
    Dim tDefinition As TaskDefinition = tService.NewTask
    tDefinition.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Tarea programada para ejecutar"
    tDefinition.Settings.RunOnlyIfLoggedOn = False
    tTime.StartBoundary = New DateTime(Fecha.Year, Fecha.Month, Fecha.Day, Fecha.Hour, Fecha.Minute, 0)
    tDefinition.Triggers.Add(tTime)
    Dim url As String = "http://localhost:5000/" & Param
    tDefinition.Actions.Add(New ExecAction("cmd.exe", "/c start " & url))
    tService.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("Test " & Param, tDefinition)
End Using
```

Comment: Vos estas queriendo hacer que esta tarea se ejecute en un SO sobre el cual no estas parado?

Comment: Si, en vez de crear la tarea en local, quiero poder generarla en el servidor.

Comment: Encontre esto, y si se puede crear una tarea desde otro pc, pero lo necesito desde vb.net
https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/cc766266(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: Ok. Tenes montones de pre requisitos que tiene que cumplir el servidor (algunos no se que tan seguro seran) y despues lo haces por linea de comandos, aunque sea desde vb. Probalo y si tenes algun problema pregunta.